# Trying to use CASE in APEX function

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a fucntion that will read in the value of a column, that is either "H", "C" or "N" and return "Hot", "Cold" or "None", but the case statement i have written keeps casuing this error:

`Error at line 5: PL/SQL: Statement ignored`

Here is my code, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, and the error is typically vague.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refreshment(
code IN string)
RETURN STRING IS
BEGIN
RETURN(
CASE code
WHEN "H" THEN "Hot"
WHEN "C" THEN "Cold"
WHEN "N" THEN "None"
END
);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `string` is not a valid date type.  You need `varchar2` instead.  Second, strings are delimited by single quotes not double quotes.

It would appear, therefore, that you want

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refreshment( p_code IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN CASE p_code
           WHEN 'H' THEN 'Hot'
           WHEN 'C' THEN 'Cold'
           WHEN 'N' THEN 'None'
         END;
END;
```